# traceroute on Linux displays '* * *'

Tags: networking, traceroute, icmp

What is going on? If I run `traceroute google.com` it outputs 192.168.0.1 for the first router (which is correct) and threee *'s for the rest. I have tried disabling the FireWall on the router (192.168.0.1) but that does not help. Any ideas?

And yes, I know there is an almost duplicate, and no, it did not help me.

Comment: the device after your router - most likely ISP device - is blocking traceroute/ping/ICMP packets. This is the reason for * * * istead of response times.

Comment: @mnmnc you should offer that as an answer rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device after your router - most likely ISP device - is blocking  ICMP protocol packets which means `traceroute` and `ping` packets.

This is the reason for * * * istead of response times

There are tools that could potentialy give the same result to you but they do not use ICMP - they use TCP. The example one is [tcptraceroute](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptraceroute). Check if this satisfy your requirements.

Comment: No go... `tcptraceroute google.com` outputs exact same thing as `traceroute google.com`... In fact, `tcptraceroute google.com` actually runs `traceroute -T -O info google.com`...